# Can I directly access a nested property in a Flask SQLAlchemy model?

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, orm, flask-sqlalchemy

I have a Flask model named `Player`,

```
class Player:
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    kills = Column(Integer)
    bot_id = Column(Integer,ForeignKey("bots.id"))
    bot = relationship("Bot",back_populates="player")
    user_id = Column(Integer,ForeignKey("users.id"))
    user = relationship("User",back_populates="player")
    player_type = Column(String) # BOT or USER
```

Both the `Bot` and `User` models have their own attributes. I want to access these attributes directly, rather than through the relationship property. This is because our frontend heavily relies on this.

For instance, instead of using `player.bot.screen_name` or `player.user.screen_name`, I want to access it like `player.screen_name`.

I can achieve this by using the following code, but I don't want to do it for each attribute as there are many.

```
@property
def screen_name(self):
    if self.player_type == "BOT":
        return self.bot.screen_name
    elif self.player_type == "USER":
        return self.user.screen_name
    else:
        return None
```

So, I attempted the following,

```
def __getattr__(self, attr):
    if hasattr(self, attr):
        return getattr(self, attr)
    elif self.player_type == "BOT" and hasattr(self.bot, attr):
        return getattr(self.bot, attr)
    elif self.player_type == "USER" and hasattr(self.user, attr):
        return getattr(self.user, attr)
    else:
        raise AttributeError(f"'{type(self).__name__}' object has no attribute '{attr}'")
```

However, this code is causing a recursion error due to `getattr`.

Is there an alternative way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

An [`association_proxy`](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/extensions/associationproxy.html#module-sqlalchemy.ext.associationproxy) may be what you are looking for.

Below is an example of how to use it.
The bot's `screen_name` attribute is directly accessible in the player object.

```py
from sqlalchemy.ext.associationproxy import association_proxy

class Bot(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'bots'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    player = db.relationship("Player",back_populates="bot")

    screen_name = db.Column(db.String)

class Player(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'players'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    # ...
    bot_id = db.Column(db.Integer,db.ForeignKey("bots.id"))
    bot = db.relationship("Bot",back_populates="player")
    screen_name = association_proxy('bot', 'screen_name')
```

```py
player = ...
print(player.screen_name)
```

Comment: like I mentioned, I don't want to do this for individual attribute as there are so many. also, the attribute is based on `player_type` condition, either Bot or User.

Comment: It seems to me that you might gain an advantage by considering an [inheritance hierarchy](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/orm/inheritance.html#mapping-class-inheritance-hierarchies) for your database model. It looks like a player is either a user or a bot and the properties seem to overlap.